# qooxdoo rest experimental

Tags: rest, qooxdoo

I am playing with REST services in qooxdoo and I have seen that there is a 
experimental class http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.6/pages/communication/rest.html

that allows to create easily the communication but I cannot find any example 
for the followings :

1. how do I pass the payload (json) to a put/post request?
2. how do I pass arguments in the url like www.example.com/customers?arg1=20

thanks in advice.

Comment: See http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.io.rest.Resource for details.

Comment: thanks ! I saw the documentation of 1.6 version ... yes this solves  the  first problem.

Comment: If you have found an answer on your own, fine, but don't add it to your question. Put it in an SO answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the 1.6 does not explain too but the documentation of 2.0 gives some clues ...

declare the specifics

```
var customers = new qx.io.rest.Resource({
  create: {
   method: "POST",
   url: "/customers"
  });
```

to put/post a payload :

```
costumers.create({   "surname": "none",
                    "name": "none",
                    "email": "someone@example.com",
                    "description": "nothing",
                    "address": "Southpole"
});
```

To pass arguments in the url :

declare the specifics

```
var customers = new qx.io.rest.Resource({
  get: {
   method: "GET",
   url: "/customers?{args}"
  });
```

and when calling

```
var arguments = "arg1=10&arg2=10";
customers.get({arg:arguments});
// this will geneterate the following http://example.com/customers?agr1=10&arg2=10
```